# Create an application to measure an object from a photo

Tags: photo, augmented-reality, photogrammetry

I am trying to devise a way of creating an application that can measure an object in a photo - automatically. So far, I have come across the following systems:

- Augmented reality
- Trigonometry + phone sensors (gyroscope)
- Known scale item in photo (credit card, etc.)

However, I have a couple of questions.

1) Which of these methods is the most efficient, especially for large batches?

2) How can I automate this process - i.e. how to get camera or software to detect the object that is going to be measured (will always be the same, i.e. a leaf), then measure it according to either augmented reality marker, scale in photo (credit card), or trig?

Any input would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to detect a particular object automatically (always the same object i.e. a stop sign) there are object detection algorithms that works adequately. a nice example is the Scale Invariant Feature Transform algorithm (SIFT)

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_sift_intro/py_sift_intro.html

But then you have the problem of photo scale which typically cannot be calculated from a single image especially if you want high acuraccy results. It can be though through stereo pairs of know geometry.

ive written those 2 articles a bit ago

http://codentonic.net/2013/06/08/camera-simulation/

http://codentonic.net/2013/06/27/camera-ray-reconstruction/

that outline a few things relative to your problem

In general you can try a combination of creating a depth map and finding the object from a feature detection algorithm. As far as it concerns the scale you can either set markers around the object with known coordinates (it will help the depth map process as well).

Generally it is not an easy task.